# Not an answer - declined. OP's answer was thanks

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21723414/1295344), as *"not an answer"* on the grounds that the OP used the Answers Section simply to give thanks and confirm that the existing answers provided the solution, which they never up voted or accepted.

I raised this so the OP would give credit correctly to the answerers, as it was surely just a misunderstanding of how to give credit to answerers through the voting system.

[image]

My flag was declined as shown below:

[image: declined]

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

I could understand if perhaps a disputed flag were given, but not an outright decline. The OP did not come to the solution by themselves, or provide any further details that hadn't been covered by the 3 existing answers which all indicate the problem.

Why am I wrong in thinking that it's not an answer given that:

- The OP is giving thanks through an answer
- The OP never credited the answerers with up votes or an accept
- The OP merely stated they forgot to include `View.` clearly given by the 3 other answers.

I am curious incase I come across this situation in the future. *But if I were an answerer, I'd be disappointed if the OP never credited me and wrote my answer as their own.*

Comment: moderators don't dispute flags, other users do. From a mod you will get declined or helpful and that's that.

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks Kate for the clarification there :)

Comment: To make you feel any better (I wish), I voted to close that in the review queue.

Comment: Scott, don't worry. Moreover, I have seen many such user/question asker who uses your answer and post their own answer without giving any credit to you (with you I mean all answer owner). An example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917146/sql-server-property-cluster-node-computer-name/24917526?noredirect=1#comment38719559_24917526

Comment: @KateGregory: I believe that a moderator *can* mark a flag as disputed rather than declined, if (s)he doesn't want to act on it but also doesn't want it to count against the flagger (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

My bad.

I assumed (yeah, I know) that the solution had been presented in the comments on the question and the OP was just answering to be able to accept an answer.

In those circumstances it would have been an answer (albeit a bad one).

I should have looked to see if there were other answers.

> Just to make it clear - I made a mistake handling **this** flag and was quite correctly called out for it here on meta. I should and (hopefully will in the future) have checked **all** the answers on the question before handling the flag. These things happen from time to time as we're only human.

The occasional declined flag isn't going to be a big problem for you. If you think a flag was declined incorrectly raise a custom flag so another moderator can double check.

Comment: I thought that may be the case. I just wanted to check for future reference. That's cool, thanks Chris.

Comment: "raise a custom flag so another moderator can double check" Really? Most of the time the mods agree, and people (the mods + meta) think you're wasting their time.

Comment: "I assumed (yeah, I know) that the solution had been presented in the comments on the question and the OP was just answering to be able to accept an answer." What? So I can just post an answer with "thanks" if someone wrote the answer in the comments to the questin? I think acceptance of not-an-answer flags should *not* be context-sensitive. Either an answer is an actual (however bad) answer or it isn't. I believe the answer in question was clearly just a thanks, and the existence of other comments shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Bakuriu - no you can't. It will get down-voted/flagged and someone paying more attention than me will delete it. The problem here was that **I** wasn't giving the flag my full attention when I handled it. I should have looked at the whole picture, not just the answer in isolation.

Comment: So, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655692/python-parse-extract-specific-data/24655968#24655968 you have another example - my flag was declined. The flag was "This is a link only answer" - what else except for the name of Beautiful Soup and the link do you see in that answer???

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - that was a different moderator who handled that flag so I can't say why they declined it.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm not blaming you. I just wanted to point out that it's a similar case. Could you handle this appropriately?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - flag it again and it will get looked at again.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Note that the two examples you provided are different. The first is just "Hey guys, thanks for the help", the second is "Try to use this library". The first one simply doesn't *attempt* to answer the question. It doesn't even *try* to solve the problem. The second one *does* attempt to provide a solution, even though the answer is a *really* bad one without much explanation.  Not an answer flag aren't about the helpfulness of the answer, but about the *intention*. This second example is a very low quality answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu anyway: Link only answers and questions about recommended libraries are off-topic at SO. Why in the world it's fine to keep an answer which consists only of a link to a library then? If I encounter such thing in a review test and let it stay here, I would definitely see "STOP. Look and listen..." then. What we are really discussing now on this Meta question is: What to do if legitimate flag was declined by someone who didn't pay attention.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I did **not** say that that answer should stay. I said that the answer should be deleted *as a very-low quality answer* and not as not-an-answer. You simply got the reason wrong when flagging.

Comment: @Bakuriu I've chosen a custom flag and described the issue as "This is a link only answer".

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Note that what you described as "custom flag" is *other (**needs ♦ moderator attention**)*. In other words that kind of flag should be used for particular circumstances where usual flags cannot be handled by (community) reviewers. In your case the answer was simply very low quality (link only answers are considered as such), so there is **no** need for ♦ moderator attention and you should have flagged it as *very low quality*. ♦ moderators already have lots to do, so don't just drop them flags that could be handled easily by the community.

Comment: _"I should have looked at the whole picture, not just the answer in isolation."_ I think the point was that the answer in isolation was enough to know that it should be deleted.

Comment: @Oktalist - not necessarily. If the bit about the `View` being missing had **only** been in comments then it would have been a valid answer.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Same if `View` had not been mentioned in comments or anywhere else. Just a low quality answer.

Comment: You guys are always saying that comments are second class citizens and could be removed at any time, so I don't see why the hypothetical content of comments factored into this decision _at all_, at _any_ level. The content of the post is clearly not an answer, by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the claim made by ChrisF (not sure whether you dispute this) is that "i forgot to write View" would qualify it as a (bad) answer *if* that didn't already appear in other answers. He has also explained why comments are relevant -- the reason he assumed that it didn't already appear in answers is that he wrongly guessed that it was transferring information from comments. The volatile nature of comments is exactly why they're somewhat relevant -- it's legitimate to make an answer that repeats comments, it's not legitimate to make an answer that repeats answers.

Comment: ... so I guess even when he hasn't made a wrong guess, ChrisF's imagination stretches further than yours, and what is clear to you is not clear to everyone ;-p

Answer (score 4):

I started out thinking ChrisF made a big mistake and then I see where he was coming from and he shouldn't beat himself up so much. **The answer should not have been deleted** - it should have been **edited** to say: *"I fixed my problem by using the Class Name View in front of invisible."* - The way it is written, it looks like Not An Answer, but that flag is reserved for gibberish. This is an answer, not a great one. Then OP could have accepted his answer.

An alternative to OP's answer that was deleted would have been a comment on one of the other answers.

Comment: The problem is the *other* answers already say that so there was no need for the OP to post an answer at all.

Comment: @ChrisF: There is no duplicate answer flag last I checked. If it was a bad answer, it should have been downvoted.

Comment: That answer has been downvoted, though.

Comment: That's true duplicate answers are permitted, but it defeats the purpose of SO if the OP copies the information provided by other answerers without adding anything further to the solution; And in particular without giving credit where credit is due to the people that solved the problem. The OP was just giving thanks incorrectly. And it's understandable the actions taken by Chris.

Comment: @staticx - there's so much cruft at times, don't feel bad about flagging it. Rather than flagging it for moderator attention, just flag and select "Its not an answer" and let the community handle it.